# Why do I need a space before the '^' operator in VBA for Excel 2013 or it will produce a compile time error "Expected list or separator"

Tags: vba, excel-2013, vba7

If I type for example `Sqr(a ^ 2 + b ^ 2)` there  is no error. But when I type `Sqr(a ^ 2 + b^ 2)` it produces a compile error which I do not understand:

[image: pic]

What is the function of `^` in VBA7 as opposed to `_^` (underscore to show space) which denotes exponentiation?

Comment: VBA Editor should add the extra spaces between `r ^ 2` for you. If it's not doing that there is something wrong it but what's actually wrong I don't know :O

Comment: No repro in Excel 2010, so this must be an Excel 2013 issue.

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisCorbett no repro in 2013 neither

Comment: Well I was expecting for the editor to add the spaces, but it doesn't. It produces the compile error. The error comes when I type `r^ 2` also. I have 64-bit Office 2013

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a 64 bit [issue.](https://support.microsoft.com/en-gb/help/2454019/the-64-bit-office-2010-vba-compiler-shows-an-error-when-it-encounters)

^ can confuse the compiler as to whether an operator versus operand value as LongLong is being used.

This problem occurs because the circumflex character (^) is ambiguous in this context. For 64-bit versions of VBA, the circumflex has two meanings:

1. It can designate an exponent operation, such as x to the power of y ("x^y").
2. For 64-bit Office 2010 VBA editions only, it can designate that an operand value should be treated as a LongLong, 64-bit integer value data type (for example, "234^").

> Consider the following scenario:
>
> You have the 64-bit edition of Microsoft Office 2010 installed on your
>   computer. In the Visual Basic IDE, you create a new project.
>
> In your Visual Basic for Applications (VBA) code, you type a statement
>   that resembles the following:
>
> LongLongVar2 = LongLongVar1^IntegerVar
>
> When you type x^y in the 64-bit Office 2010 VBA editions, the VBA IDE
>   editor does not know how to interpret the "x^" part of the string. In
>   this context, "x^" can be treated as being the LongLong data type. If
>   "x^" is interpreted in this manner, the string will produce an error
>   because there is no operator that is specified for the "y" value to
>   apply to the "x" value. If you type the string by using a space
>   between the value name and the circumflex (for example, x ^y), you
>   indicate that you intend the symbol to be an operator and not a data
>   type designator. By doing this, you can avoid the error condition.
>   Therefore, the example expression ... should be rewritten as follows:
>
> LongLongVar2 = LongLongVar1 ^ IntegerVar

Comment: So `2^^2=4` as it will be interpreted as `(2^)^2 = (2)^2 = 4`?

Comment: So, if I want to raise `foo` to the `bar` power, where both are of type `Double`, how does that happen?

Answer (score 0):

Using ^^ seems to still have some conflicts:

```
?(-1)^^2 
"Compile Error: Expected: expression"
```

But I've found enclosing both terms in parentheses for ^ seems to work.

```
?(-1)^(2)
1
```

Same with variables:

```
foo = -1
bar = 2
?foo^^bar
"Compile Error: Type-declaration character does not match declared data type"

(foo)^(bar)
1
```